# VS2010: "Cannot find the resource compiler DLL. Please make sure the path is correct."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've been following [theForger's win32 API tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/menus.html), and I decided to open the `menu_one.rc` file to see its contents from within VS2010, and I got this error:

[image: The error (imgur.com)]

I've double-checked both locations and neither of the files actually exist. The only copies of rcdll.dll I have are located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\rcdll.dll and 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\rcdll.dll
```

I've tried doing a [repair install of the Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717422%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle2), but that didn't fix the problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This thread](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/525412/missing-rcdll-dll-file) mentions a registry issue:

> I had been able to reproduce the issue with my pc with Windows 7 SP1 64 bit and VS2010 Sp1 installed.
>
> What I had to is modify the following registry entries from

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows]
"CurrentVersion"="7.0"
"CurrentInstallFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0\\"
```

> to

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows]
"CurrentVersion"="7.0.30319"
"CurrentInstallFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\"
```

> And there were 2 keys under

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows]
```

> which are

```
v7.0
v7.0A
```

> I deleted v7.0 along with all its subkeys. And the problem is solved.

Comment: This is how those keys are laid out on my box: http://i.imgur.com/vORBK.png How should I proceed?

Comment: @whiplash I believe the idea is to make sure those keys references the directory where you `rcdll.dll` actually, with the current version to v7.0A in your case

Comment: Changing the registry key to reflect 7.0A's install directory did the trick. Restarted VS2010 and the .rc file opened just fine! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7):

I was a little worried about changing the registry since I'm running on v8.0A, but I was able to fix the error by simply copying the rcdll.dll from previous version into the directory listed in the error message.

Comment: I tried the same with no luck.  Changing the reg key as indicated by @VonC did, however, correct the problem... perhaps not correctly, but it functions.

Comment: May be you copied the wrong file. There is a 32 bit and a 64 bit version of this DLL. For me it worked.

Answer (score 1):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770114/975724) is helpful, but in my case it did not solve the problem.  There was another registry key that needed to change.

To find that key, I searched **regedit** for `v6.0A` since that was the version in the path on my error dialog.
The dialog path was `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\rcdll.dll`

Once the key containing `v6.0A` was found, I replaced the path with what it was on my machine:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`

I also updated the version strings to be `v7.0A` or `7.0.30319` depending on what the original value was.  I found a few of version strings in sub-keys of my search result, so I applied the changes there as well.

On my machine, the key that Visual Studio was using was located in:

```
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-627493193-880714491-1605132347-6179\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows]
```