# VS 2013 Cannot find the resource compiler DLL. Please make sure the path is correct

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc, visual-studio-2013

Unlike the other questions I've found on SO and elsewhere, this error is shown but no path is listed above the message, just the text:

> Cannot find the resource compiler DLL.
>   Please make sure the path is correct.

Followed by another error:

> The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error

I've tried logging and nothing different comes up, shows the same errors.

Tried the registry edit mentioned [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770084/vs2010-cannot-find-the-resource-compiler-dll-please-make-sure-the-path-is-cor) and in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330701/vs2012-cannot-find-the-resource-compiler-dll-please-make-sure-the-path-is-cor).  I have 3 keys in my registry directory

> HKEY-LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6443Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows

1. v7.1A (the one I want that has the resource dll)
2. v8.0A
3. v8.1A

I deleted the 8.0* and still nothing.  I've repaired VS to try to fix any issues but that didn't work.  Tried adding the DLL directly to VS bin folder, putting the directory in the project Compile configuration, and added it to the PATH variable but nothing has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Oh Lord, don't delete those keys.  This kind of frivolous registry hacking is what is getting you into trouble like this.  Reinstall.

Comment: Yeah wasn't too worried about breaking it honestly, since it didn't work to begin with and I was looking at a complete Windows and VS reinstall anyways.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is definitely in the path to the resource dll, namely `rcdll.dll`,  which the Visual Studio (`devenv.exe`) is reading from the registry. Try the key

```
HKEY-LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6443Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1
```

Create it if it is absent, and add string parameter `InstallationFolder` with the path to the installed SDK:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\
```

Studio should accept this path. Then studio may not find dll in the path, this time showing the missing path in the message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\bin\x86\rcdll.dll
```

Put (copy) dll to this path - this should be enough.

The main thing is to discover, **which exactly registry key** is studio reading. Here the utility [procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645) from [Sysinternals Suit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) will help - it tracks all accesses to the registry of specified process (`devenv.exe`). So, if specified paths above will be different in your configuration, use `procmon` and just track the registry key which is queried.

Comment: I pointed the registry key at the Windows Kit rather than copying rcdll.dll. The kit is located at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0.  This will resolve any problems with VS reporting that it cannot open the x86 or x64 version of the DLL.  It will also ensure that the DLL is the correct version.

Comment: @JeremyWhitcher How did you do that? Could you show step by step, please?